# proper use google webmaster tools URL Parameters

Tags: seo, google-search-console

There are some urls like `http://domain.com/user/:username` and `http://domain.com/post/:id` on my website, the username and id is the parameter from database.
I try to let google crawler more efficiently , can I use `google webmaster tools > URL Parameters > add parameter` ? I read the document but still don't get it how to set up?
the column `Parameter` and the rest what should I filled? or this tools only for `get` method parameter?
[image]     [image]

Answer (score 1):

The URL parameter page is there for old-fashioned URLs with query strings attached.

For example:  http://www.example.com/index.php?A=1&B=2

This page should explain more: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550

Comment: so if I change mine to old-fashioned ,then use this tool, compare the url style curret I use, does that better or not for help seo/google crawler ?

Comment: There is nothing "old-fashioned" about query strings.

Comment: @w3d if I change my url from `domain.com/user/:username` to `doamin.com/q?user=:username` better for google crawler? because there is not a tool  setting up parameter for google crawler if I use `domain.com/user/:username`

Comment: @user1775888 Well, it's not necessarily any better (or worse) for "google crawler", but it does mean you can use the tool in Google Search Console (aka GWT) to control how Google interprets URL parameters.

Answer (score 1):

> To be eligible for this feature, the URL parameters must be configured
>   in key/value pairs like item=swedish-fish or category=gummy-candy in
>   the URL
>   http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish&category=gummy-candy.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/configuring-url-parameters-in-webmaster.html

Comment: if I change my url from `domain.com/user/:username` to `doamin.com/q?user=:username` better for google crawler? because there is not a tool  setting up parameter for google crawler if I use `domain.com/user/:username`

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs in form of `http://example.com/user/:username` will already be crawled. Here `:username` is the parameter judged by your JS MVC framework (Angular, Vue or otherwise) in its Route configuration. The URL parameters are [made of a key and a value separated by an equals sign (=) and joined by an ampersand (&)](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6277564?hl=en).

The URL parameter section in Webmaster console lets you control how to interpret indexed pages with the above mentioned URL parameters.
Suppose you were having a product page as well with its URL being `http://example.com/product?pid=143&pbrand=nike` and another similar one as `http://example.com/product?pid=143&pbrand=nike&sessionId=110029021`. In this case, the parameter keys like `pid` and `pbrand` are supposed to be active parameters.

> Active parameters can change page content

On the other hand, sessionId is more likely to be a passive parameter.

> Passive URL parameters have no affect on how content appears to the user; they are often used to track visits and referrers.

[More about active and passive parameters](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550)